# Accessing a delegate's input value from the model

Tags: qt, delegates, qabstractitemmodel

I'm using a custom `QTableView` with a custom `QAbstractTableModel` and a `QItemDelegate`. I'd need to access the contents of the delegate's editor while the user is editing it, and after several attempts, I couldn't find anything satisfying.

Indeed, I've tried several things. 
First: trying to access the delegate's current input (created through `createEditor`) through a property defined in `QItemDelegate` but... it seems that none exists. That's why I tried to add a `QWidget* editor` property and setting it in the `createEditor`. 
Unfortunately, `QItemDelegate`'s `createEditor` is supposed to be const, which makes me unable to set my property there (and since I don't control what calls `createEditor`, I can't do it before or after).

I don't really know what to do here. Actually, I also needed to know when the user started (or stopped) editing the cell content, which I eventually achieved by creating two `const` signals (`editingStarted` and `editingStopped`). I could probably create a `const` `editorOpened(QWidget*)` signal but it just feels bad and ugly...

I can't believe nothing "official" exists to achieve what I'm trying to do, hence this question. If I have everything wrong from the beginning, I'd be glad to know. If you have any other ideas, please suggest.

**EDIT: Here is a minimal working example**

**MainWindow.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QTableView>
#include "mytableview.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto tableView = new MyTableView(this);
    setCentralWidget(tableView);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

**MyItemDelegate.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MYITEMDELEGATE_H
#define MYITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QStandardItemModel>

class MyItemDelegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyItemDelegate(QObject* parent);

    virtual QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    virtual void onCloseEditor();

    virtual ~MyItemDelegate() = default;

signals:
    // Const signals trick
    void editingStarted() const;
    void editingFinished() const;
    void editorOpened(const QWidget*) const;
};

#endif // MYITEMDELEGATE_H
```

**MyItemDelegate.cpp**

```cpp
#include "myitemdelegate.h"

MyItemDelegate::MyItemDelegate(QObject* parent) : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
    connect(this, &QItemDelegate::closeEditor, this, &MyItemDelegate::onCloseEditor);
}

QWidget* MyItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    auto lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
    emit editingStarted();
    emit editorOpened(lineEdit);
    return lineEdit;
}

void MyItemDelegate::onCloseEditor()
{
    emit editingFinished();
}
```

**MyTableView.h**

```cpp
#ifndef MYTABLEVIEW_H
#define MYTABLEVIEW_H

#include <QTableView>
#include <QDebug>
#include "myitemdelegate.h"

class MyTableView : public QTableView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyTableView(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MYTABLEVIEW_H
```

**MyTableView.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mytableview.h"

MyTableView::MyTableView(QWidget *parent) : QTableView(parent)
{
    MyItemDelegate* delegate = new MyItemDelegate(this);
    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    setItemDelegate(delegate);
    setModel(model);

    QList<QList<QStandardItem*>> items;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items << QList<QStandardItem*>();
        for (int j = 'A'; j < 'E'; j++)
            items[i] << new QStandardItem(QString("%1,%2").arg(i).arg(static_cast<char>(j)));
    }

    for (const auto& row : items)
        model->appendRow(row);

    connect(delegate, &MyItemDelegate::editingStarted, []() {
        qDebug() << "Editing started";
    });

    connect(delegate, &MyItemDelegate::editingFinished, []() {
        qDebug() << "Editing finished";
    });

    connect(delegate, &MyItemDelegate::editorOpened, [](const QWidget* editor) {
        auto lineEdit = qobject_cast<const QLineEdit*>(editor);
        connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, [](const QString& text) {
            qDebug() << text;
        });
    });
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: Example output]

Comment: From where do you need to access the content of the delegate?

Comment: Either the `TableView` or, even better, the `TableView`'s parent.

Comment: Can you please show a minimal complete example of what you are trying to do? It would really help to understand this interesting question.

Comment: I added a minimal example that shows how I used a `const` signal to notify that editing has started and ended, as well as how I used another `const` signal to pass the editor to the parent `QTableView` (and it works). But nested lambdas? I don't like that.

Comment: I think you must not to handle editor's events in the context of your table view. Did you consider using `QAbstractItemDelegate::setModelData()`?

Comment: @vahancho `setModelData` is called when the changes are commited and the editor closed, which is not what I'm looking for (I need to get the new data as soon as the user types something, to dispay it somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution maybe fits your needs. I just defined a new signal inside the delegate and connected to it inside the class owning the delegate.

**MyItemDelegate.h**

```
#ifndef MYITEMDELEGATE_H
#define MYITEMDELEGATE_H

#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

class MyItemDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MyItemDelegate(QObject* parent);

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;

    virtual ~MyItemDelegate() = default;

signals:
    void valueChanged(const QString&);
};

#endif // MYITEMDELEGATE_H
```

**MyItemDelegate.cpp**

```
#include "myitemdelegate.h"
#include <QLineEdit>

MyItemDelegate::MyItemDelegate(QObject* parent) : QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget* MyItemDelegate::createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const
{
    auto lineEdit = new QLineEdit(parent);
    connect(lineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &MyItemDelegate::valueChanged);
    return lineEdit;
}
```

**MyTableView.cpp**

```
#include "mytableview.h"
#include <QStandardItemModel>

MyTableView::MyTableView(QWidget *parent) : QTableView(parent)
{
    MyItemDelegate* delegate = new MyItemDelegate(this);
    QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    setItemDelegate(delegate);
    setModel(model);

    QList<QList<QStandardItem*>> items;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        items << QList<QStandardItem*>();
        for (int j = 'A'; j < 'E'; j++)
            items[i] << new QStandardItem(QString("%1,%2").arg(i).arg(static_cast<char>(j)));
    }

    for (const auto& row : items)
        model->appendRow(row);

    connect(delegate, &MyItemDelegate::valueChanged, [](auto v) { qDebug() << v; });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Actually, it's pretty much the same thing that I did in my `MyItemDelegate` (unless I actually emitted the signal with the `QWidget*` that I had  create, which better fitted my case). I admit, though, that your solution which avoids the nested lambdas, looks cleaner.
If you have technical reasons why using your implementation would be better than mine, I'd be glad to hear them obviously.

Comment: @ThomasKowalski: As for me there are no reasons to have nested lambdas in the code. I have quite some of them. Just wanted to prove, that in this case they are not really necessary.

Comment: Yes, that's true.